# SLURM submitting program with different parameters in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, slurm

How do i run one program with different parameters in parallel on multiple nodes with `SLURM`?
Example, I want to run:

```
prog a1.txt
prog a2.txt
prog a3.txt
...
prog an.txt
```

on `m`, `m<n`, cluster nodes but only one at a time, that is when `prog ai.txt` is run on node `j`, no other `prog aj.txt` (an instance of `prog`) is executed until this one is finished. Each instance of `prog ai.txt` will use `k` cores on the given node during some part of its execution. So inititially:

```
prog a1.txt runs on node 1
prog a2.txt runs on node 2
...
prog am.txt runs on node m
```

and once `prog a1.txt` ends on `node 1`,  `prog am+1.txt` will run on `node 1` etc.

Ideally, i would like to be able to achieve this with a SLURM script.

I have already asked [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62648824/slurm-running-multiple-openmp-jobs-each-on-a-single-node-with-script) but without an answer that i would understand and the documentation does not provide a "SLURM guide to an idiot". To avoid comments such as "why do i want to run it on `m` nodes?", this is what i am allocated, this is what i want, running it on less is not using all the resources, and i cannot run it on more. The important thing is that `SLURM` MUST NOT assign 2 or more of those instances to a given node at the same time even if the `prog` on that node is at that moment using only one core, this I cannot stress enough, this is what i want to achieve.

Comment: See if this utility helps you: https://github.com/TACC/pylauncher
Contact me directly if it needs adaptation to your system.

Comment: Can SLURM job arrays help you here?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet That depends, are job arrays executed in parallel each array member on exactly one node?

Comment: If your sysadmin allows several jobs (at least from the same user) then yes if you ask for it.

Comment: If a single SLURM parallel job is a hard constraint, have a look at the Flux framework from LLNL. One use case is to start a private resource manager within a single SLURM allocation, and then you have huge flexibility.

Comment: Please remove the OpenMP tag. This has nothing to do with OpenMP.